# How do batch copy and rename files with same names under different folders to a separate folder with files renamed to their parent folder in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

Say I have folders named `user/john/john1`, `john2` and `john3` and I have one file called `dog.txt` inside each of them. I want to create a separate folder called `johns_dogs` and copy all the `dog.txt` from each folder into this new folder, but with the files renamed as `john1_dog.txt`, `john2_dog.txt`, `john3_dog.txt`.

How would I go about this? I assume I can use a for loop for this, and I have been playing around with it..i just can't seem to get it right; specifically isolating the folder names to apply to the file name using the linux terminal. Using GUI is not an option. Thank you :)

```bash
for fname in user/john/*/dog.txt;
do
  new_name=basename $(PWD)
  cp user/john/*/dog.txt > $new_name.txt;
done
```

This is what I've tried to do...but it doesn't work, and i don't know why?

Comment: Your use of `new_name= basename $(PWD)` seems problematic due to the space after the equals sign and the lack of capturing the output from the `basename` command.  Further, your new_name variable does not contain the path to the new `johns_dogs` directory.

Comment: Typo `new_name= basename $(PWD)` superfluous space `' '` removed on right of `'='`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use bash string substitution via parameter expansion to build the desired output path for each file:

```
for f in ./user/john/*/dog.txt ; do 
    new="${f//\//_}"
    new="${new/._user_john_/./johns_dogs/}"
    cp "$f" "$new"
done
```

or as one-liner:

```
for f in ./user/john/*/dog.txt ; do new="${f//\//_}" ; new="${new/._user_john_/./johns_dogs/}" ; cp "$f" "$new"; done
```

After running above command contents of `.johns_dogs` directory:

```
find ./johns_dogs/*
./johns_dogs/john1_dog.txt
./johns_dogs/john2_dog.txt
./johns_dogs/john3_dog.txt
./johns_dogs/john4_dog.txt
./johns_dogs/john5_dog.txt
```

String replacement details:

```
new="${f//\//_}"  # replace all '/' with '_' in original path to create new path
```

```
new="${new/._user_john_/./johns_dogs/}" # replace '._user_john_' with './johns_dogs' to complete new path
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of some utterly incomprehensible, works-by-voodoo-magic, write-test-debug-then-throw-away script, my approach in similar cases is as follows:

- Use the `ls` command to create a "long" listing of your files.
  (One full filename per line.)
- Pipe it into a text file.
- Open the text file in an editor which supports column editing.
- Copy the column of filenames to the clipboard.
- While keeping the copied column in the clipboard:

  - Edit the column of filenames, so as to turn them into the destination filenames. (Use column-mode and/or search-and-replace for this.)
- Paste the column of original filenames from the clipboard into the text file, right before the column of altered filenames.
- Prepend `cp`  at the start of each line.
- Save the text file as a shell script. (Prepend `#!bash`, do the necessary `chmod`)
- Run the shell script.

It might seem like a lot of work, but actually you can do it very quickly (as long as you do not have to manually modify each line) and the great benefit of it is that you can just examine it with your eyes and have a fairly high degree of confidence that once run, it will do the right thing, whereas the script might destroy your filesystem and you will only know after the fact.

I mean, please do not get me wrong, I am a Software Engineer, I write code for a living, I solve problems by writing code, but there are some cases where it is just not worth writing code.

Comment: And you can merge the two approaches: in the voodoo script, replace the "mv $oldname $newname" with 'echo mv "$oldname" "$newname", then run the voodoo script piping it to /tmp/devoodoed.sh', then inspect the resulting script to verify that the magic did indeed work. I usually do that. 99% of the times the voodoo worked; the remaining 1%, visually inspecting the script before running it has saved my nether regions.